# PHP server access the posted value from the Angular2

Tags: php, angular

Hii I am working with angular2 and php. In my project I want to post the json into the php page , and access it in the server side . How can I make it possible??

in my angular2 , when I click on the button SaveData() will called.

```
SaveData()
    {
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');      
      let body = JSON.stringify(this.Cost);
      this.http.post('http://192.168.0.100:80/php/test.php',body,{headers})
      .subscribe(
        data => console.log('Received:' + data),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('Call Complete')
      ); 
    }
```

an in my PHP page I used like..

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
$post = $_POST['body'];
$fp = fopen('a.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp,$post);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

What is the best solution for this??

Answer (score 2):

When you post json data you can retrieve it manually using

```
 $post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
```

the above line will return you the posted json data in array format.

if you want to check what is posted then you can use

```
print_r($post);
```

To save json in file modify the code as below

```
$post = file_get_contents("php://input");
$fp = fopen('a.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp,$post);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: thanks for Your time@Gautam. My posting data is a json String . I want to save it as a json file . Is it possible ?